# How does one split a QT(C++) UI into multiple widget subclasses and get it to display the same as all in the same class?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm learning QT (I already know C++ very well) and trying to get a UI to display well but I do **not** want to use the QT Designer that comes with QT Creator.  I have the following class:

```
#include "MainPanel.h"
#include<QVBoxLayout>

MainPanel::MainPanel(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QLayout *lo = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    mList = new QListWidget(this);

    mList->addItem("Testing");
    setLayout(lo);
    lo->addWidget(mList);
    lo->setSpacing(5);
}
```

The Main window class has a bunch of extra protected functions but the initControls method just does this:

```
void MainWindow::initControls()
{
    QHBoxLayout *loMain = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    loMain->addWidget(new MainPanel(this));
    setLayout(loMain);
}
```

When I put all the code from MainPanel into MainWindow::initControls() or even in the constructor(either way), it works - shows a list widget with a single item "Testing".  With the code in MainPanel though, it shows up as a very small rectangle that wouldn't fit the word "Testing" nor is there any semblance of text in there even partially.

I have tried to override sizeHint() in and move the code to create and return the list widget to a method getList() so I can access it from sizeHint too but that did nothing - I still get a small rectangle.

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do or include to get the widget to paint properly?  I have more controls I want to add to this UI (a button panel below the list widget and a detail panel on the right 2/3 of the window) but until I can get this to display, I can't possibly proceed with the rest.

I also want to do this entirely with code - not using the designer as I have vision issues and found it to be difficult to place things correctly on the form.

Someone please help - documentation and tutorials other than the documentation on QT's website is helpful if it points me to the right direction.  I have already looked on QT's docs site under QWidget, QListWidget, QLayout, and QH(and V)BoxLayouts but see nothing and many of the tutorials talk about the designer.

Before someone tries to scold about creating a SSME or whatever small program - I have given you the smallest one that displays the issue - I know that putting the code all into the main window fixes it but one should never have everything in one class.

Comment: Your "MSVE" is fine, though you could show a bit of MainPanel. First guess: MainPanel is a custom (or not) widget, that is placed on the MainWindow? And you do `new QHBoxLayout(this);` for it, right? Those layouts are gui classes, that manage other widgets' positions and size, those that you add to them. They are set for the containing widgets and do the trick. So, the guess is that you've handled widget positioning _inside_ MainPanel, but nothing is available for MainWindow do deal with it;s content, thus the unappropriate effect. Could that guess be right?
Try Designer before code, really))

Comment: The only thing I left out of the MainPanel was the sizeHint() and getList() methods which I had removed because like I said - it did not work.  I was trying to just split off MainPanel to get the List box to display properly there, then I would have known what worked and repeated that for future widgets to add more controls.  You're right about the new QHBoxLayout(this) but only for the MainWindow() - I pasted the initControls() method of MainWindow which is where I put control placement logic.  Normally I would create a getter like getMainPanel() but I can't even get it to display right.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use designer too effectively - I've been trying since I posted this question and while I can get the list widget on, the button panel below the list widget  I can't get as I keep accidentally dropping the buttons onto the list widget and not onto the qwidget that I want to make into the button panel.  I have issues with my vision so the detail I'm seeing isn't enough I guess and I have to use the XML which I don't understand one bit. :-(

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't get it, despite you've provided all the info -- do you have _two_ layouts (one for MainPanel with ListWidget, another -- for MainWindow with MainPanel) in that case, which looks bad?

Comment: The difference when you move the code from `MainPanel::MainPanel` into `MainWindow::initControls` is that the `this` is now the `MainWindow` and not `MainPanel`.  So `setLayout(lo);` is setting the layout of `MainWindow` where previously it was setting the layout of `MainPanel`.  This might interfere with the other line:  `setLayout(loMain);`.

Comment: Oh! And do you have something like `MainWindow w; w.resize(400, 500); w.show();` there to make MainWindow big enough?

Comment: I do the MainWindow wnd; wnd.show() in the main() function.  I want to move that to a subclass of QApplication honestly but just haven't yet because I had run into some seg fault exceptions and reverted earlier.  Anyhow, I have QHBoxLayout in MainWindow and QVBoxLayout in MainPanel().  Now since I commented last, I noticed something in a QT documentation site - I don't ever call setCentralWidget - I use MainPanel as my central widget but would that maybe cause the problems I'm having?

Comment: And to answer your question - The UI that looks bad is the one where I put some of the code in the MainPanel and call MainPanel from MainWindow.  If I put it all in MainWindow then it works pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, too unclear, what's happening there, we should have requested for more of your code =)

Here is the smallest possible sample, demonstrating what you should have been trying to achieve:

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mainpanel.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    MainPanel* p = new MainPanel(this);
    setCentralWidget(p);
}
```

**mainpanel.h:**

```
#include "mainpanel.h"

#include <QListWidget>
#include <QLayout>

MainPanel::MainPanel(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QLayout *lo = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QListWidget* mList = new QListWidget(this);

    mList->addItem("Testing");
    setLayout(lo);
    lo->addWidget(mList);
    lo->setSpacing(5);
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.resize(400, 500);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Seemingly, you've tried to set a layout on `QMainWindow`, but it already has a built-in layout, it is exactly the case when `setCentralWidget` should work, leave manual layout creation for `QWidget` & `QDialog` subclasses.

The code above works fine, try it and refactor the way you want.

Comment: Awesome!  Worked like a charm!  Now I can advance and hopefully figure out QT better as I continue w/ my application.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

@MasterAler is correct that the root cause of your issue is setting a layout MainWindow.  The reason for using a MainWindow is to support standard VBoxLayout of menubar, central widget, and status bar.  So it makes no sense to set your own layout for a QMainWindow.

Since we didn't have your entire code, I didn't assume MainWindow was a `QMainWindow`.  I got your code to work by making MainWindow a `QDialog`.  This may be more of what you were originally looking for, where you want to put a widget of your own making into any container.  Following is in Python (I find Python a faster prototyping environment than C++), but you can easily read it and see how to host your `MainPanel` is any widget (not just a `MainWindow`):

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListWidget, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout

class MainPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        lo = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lo.setSpacing(5)
        self.setLayout(lo)

        mList = QListWidget(self)
        mList.addItem("Testing")
        lo.addWidget(mList)


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        loMain = QHBoxLayout(self)
        loMain.addWidget(MainPanel(self))
        self.setLayout(loMain)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Show the form
    window = MainWindow(None)
    window.exec_()
```

Comment: I fixed it by just setting central widget - I didn't know at all that I needed to do that or what a central widget was but on the other hand I was trying to set a central widget anyhow.  I have 17 years of Java and Swing (their version of QT essentially) experience and use BorderLayout a lot in which you have a single component in the N, S, E, and W, and the center - I was trying to replicate that thinking there was no layout there already.  So now I know for the future.  My next project I expect to be an Android one so this would be useful to know!  Thank you still :)